# Isomorphism between submodules as one-sided ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with 1, and $I$ and $J$ be  left ideasl of $R$ such that they are isomorphic as left $R$-modules. Is it true that the left ldeals $I^2$ and $J^2$ are isomorphic ?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's no reason for $I^2 = J^2$. (I'm not sure what else you might mean by "isomorphic as left ideals")

Comment: I guess the title should be "... between one-sided ideals as (sub)modules" and accordingly, you ask whether $I^2$ and $J^2$ are isomorphic as modules.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but if $phi:I\rightarrow J$ is an $R$-module iso with inverse $\psi$, is its restriction to $I^2$ not an R-module hom. to $J^2$, with the restriction of $\psi$ to $J^2$ as its inverse?